# How to add a column to the an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

i am able to create a dynamic array entered by the use, but i need to have a starting fixed array that is not entered by the user:

**Here is an example:**

Entered and printed array is:

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

I need to add a column of 0s at the beginning of the array like so:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5

Thank you!

Comment: You could create a new array, with an extra index, and populate it again after first inserting your new starting column

Comment: Do you want to just print it that way or modify the actual matrix?

Comment: modify the actual matrix to have an extra column at the beginning @Reddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you enter 3 rows and 2 columns for r and c. Then input the values. The output is:

1 2

1 2

1 2

But now I want that to appear as:

0 1 2

0 1 2

0 1 2

The number of rows (vertical) is the same. But the number of columns (horizontal) has increased from 2 to 3 since I've added the extra column for 0's.

So in code we have to account for the extra column:

```
    int r;
    int c;
    Console.Write("Enter number of rows: ");
    r = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter number of columns: ");
    c = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    c++; //add an extra column for the added 0's
    int[,] matrix = new int[r, c];
```

Now we want to add the 0's to this column. But we need to be able to specify that we only want to add 0's for the first column. When we're filling the arrays we can add a check to say that if the column we are currently filling is the very first column for a row then automatically insert a 0.

```
    for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
        {
            if (col == 0)
            {
                matrix[row, col] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ", row, col);
                matrix[row, col] = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
```

The first entry that the user is asked to enter is no longer {0,0} since the very first entry would've been automatically entered, but do you really care? If so you can just minus 1 from the display value there:

```
    Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ", row, col -1);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly sir! thank you and thumbs up to you for the extra explanation you provided !

Answer (score 3):

You just need to initialize the matrix with an extra column and fill it in with the values you need before filling the remainder of the matrix with the values entered by the user:

```
//...
     int[,] matrix = new int[r, c + 1];

     /*Insert Values into Main Matrix
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        //Fill the first column manually
        matrix[row, 0] = 0; 

        //This loop then starts from the second column, and loops until
        //col <= c instead of just col < c
        for (int col = 1; col <= c; col++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ", row, col);
            matrix[row, col] = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you use a *wrong collection type*: 2D array `int[,]` instead of `List<List<int>>`:

```
  ...
  // Initialization is quite a complex, but it's the only such a fragment  
  List<List<int>> matrix = Enumerable
    .Range(1, r)              // r columns
    .Select(i => Enumerable   // i - row index which we ignore
      .Range(1, c)            // c columns 
      .Select(index => 0)     // assign each item to 0 
      .ToList())              // inner list
    .ToList();                // outer list

  for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
  {
     for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
     {
        Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ", row, col);
        // please, notice [row][col] instead of [row, col]
        matrix[row][col] = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     }
  }
```

Or you can even *generate* the initial matrix

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

```
   List<List<int>> matrix = Enumerable
     .Range(1, 4)               // 4 rows
     .Select(i => Enumerable    // i - row index which we ignore
        .Range(1, 5)            // 5 columns
        .Select(index => index) // assign 1, 2, ..., 5 to row items
        .ToList())              // inner list
     .ToList();                 // outer list
```

without any user input. And when you want to add up a column, it's as easy as

```
  foreach (var row in matrix)
    row.Insert(0, 0);
```

inserting `0` at `0`th position of an each `row`. Test

```
  // join the matrix while separating rows with new lines and items with spaces 
  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, matrix
    .Select(row => string.Join(" ", row)));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Comment: I want it without user input, without user noticing it's being inserted... still i tried ur code lots of syntax error on select and insert

Comment: @Johnny: I'm sorry for typo; should be `.Select(i => Enumerable    // i - row index which we ignore` insetead of `.Select(Enumerable`: even if we don't want row index it has to be mentioned

Answer (score 1):

As a generic method, simple:

```
static TElement[,] AppendColumnOnTheLeft<TElement>(TElement[,] before)
{
  var after = new TElement[before.GetLength(0), before.GetLength(1) + 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < before.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (var j = 0; j < before.GetLength(1); ++j)
      after[i, j + 1] = before[i, j];

  return after;
}
```

The entries of the new column will all have value `default(TElement)`, i.e. `0`, `null`, `false`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
 int r;
            int c;
            Console.Write("Enter number of rows: ");
            r = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter number of columns: ");
            c = ((int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) + 1);
            int[,] matrix = new int[r, c];

            /*Insert Values into Main Matrix
             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
                {
                  if(col == 0)
                  {
                    matrix[row, col] = 0;
                  }
                  else{
                    Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ", row, col-1);
                    matrix[row, col] = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                  }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Syntax error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' on line if (col = 0)

Comment: oh yes one equal to missing added now

Answer (score 0):

Array.Copy will let you copy an array and move it over, such as

```
    int[,] arr =  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ;
    int[,] newarr = new int[6];
    Array.Copy(arr, 0, newarr, 1, arr.Length);
```

I shortened your array for typing purposes etc, but this then results in an array of {0,1,2,3,4,5} you cant just apply it to multiple rows, so you would need to itterate your rows, I thought it worked, but I checked and it doesnt. So you would then just for each row in matrix, copy row over 1 into new matrix, job done..