# How to add a column of 0s at the end of an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

the console prompts the user to enter his array, i was able to put a col of 0s before the user enters his inputs, what i need is to put also a col of 0s at the end of the array after the user finishes.

Thank you

Comment: For those who are closing as too broad .. here is the complete code which he has used  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40761005/2592042

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that you are using this code to insert 0's before your matrix. [How to add a column to the an array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760547/how-to-add-a-column-to-the-an-array-c-sharp)

The changes required for this code is

```
//c++; //remove this line
c = c + 2; //add two extra column for adding 0's, One for beginning one for end
int[,] matrix = new int[r, c];
```

Other changes are

```
    for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
      for (int col = 0; col < c - 1; col++) // reduce column loop by one
      {
        if (col == 0)
        {
          matrix[row, col] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ", row, col - 1);
          matrix[row, col] = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < c-1; col++)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ", row, col - 1);
            matrix[row, col] = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        matrix[row, col] = 0;
    }
```